# Fill the gap between shower wall and splash guard

Tags: bathroom, shower

I’m trying to install a bathtub splash guard along the lines of this [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/21933/69176). However, my bathtub is one of those pre-molded drop-in units where the shower wall corners are rounded. Also, things are not entirely square. The vertical surface of the plexiglass splash guard is 11” long and 1/2” wide. This is the surface I need to seal against the enameled tub. But with the splash guard flush to the horizontal surface of the tub the gap to the shower wall varies from 1/4” at the bottom to 1/2” at the top of the splash guard.

The splash guard came with a tube of ASI 502 100% RTV Silicone. I’m hesitant to use this product directly to try and fill such a large gap. Anyone have experience doing this? Or suggestions for alternative methods?

[image: Image highlighting the gap between shower wall and splash guard]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to tell you that that product is just not made for the application on the type of tub and tub surround that you have. If you were to try to start cutting it to fit against the tub corner and to the surround above that you would cut away the half inch edge of the splash guard leaving just the thin part to try to seal to the wall.

If I were you I would use a different approach to this. Secure a suitable sized piece of 1/2 inch thick Lexan plastic to use for a splash guard. Then cut that to fit against the form of the tub and surround. This will give you a full 1/2 inch bonding surface on all the edges. Then you can use a silicon sealer or RTV to secure that in place.

The picture below is an attempt to show you how to mark the Lexan piece so that know where to cut it.

[image]

A small block with parallel edges (red lines) can be used against the surround and tub sides (white lines) to trace a marking (green lines) over onto the Lexan piece (blue lines).

Some folks may want to use thin cardboard to create a cutting template to get the shape correct. You can still use the parallel sided block technique to transfer the shape to the cardboard.

Comment: I don’t have a band saw but I do have a handheld jigsaw. If I clamp down the lexan do you expect I could cut the curve with a jigsaw?

Comment: @Stanwood - You may be able to cut the Lexan with a jig saw if you use a blade type designed for that. I would suggest that you experiment before committing to your work piece. If you do not need a clear splash guard you could choose to use an ABS plastic instead. It cuts easier and has less chance of chipping and cracking like a plexiglass material will.